# My login codes validate my credentials ,but don't login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC.Net C# Login page and I decided to make some fancy changes, and all of the sudden my login page stoped working.
I need your help , somebody else to look at my code and may be see what I couldn't find. during debugging, it returns all true but don't go into index page. What do you think ? what is my problem that I can't see!

Here is my controller:

```
// GET: /Account/Login

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.IsUserExist(model.EMP_ID, model.EMP_PASSWORD))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EMP_ID, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The User ID or Password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: After you set the authcookie, you are returning the same Login view.

Comment: Where do you think you are telling it to go to the index view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are transferring it to any other view, you can use return `RedirectToAction("Actionname","controllername","params if any");`

```
// POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.IsUserExist(model.EMP_ID, model.EMP_PASSWORD))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EMP_ID, false);
                //change here
                return RedirectToAction("Actionname","controllername","params if any"); 

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The User ID or Password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: @NilRad dont worry it happens to everyone sometime :)

Comment: @NilRad this one will also do right,  if authenticated redirect, if not return with errors